# Extract all JSON page results with API token via dynamic looping and Excon host

Tags: json, ruby

I would like to extract **all JSON customer result pages** with the API token (via dynamic looping). By default, it shows results obtained from the first page only. The code is as attached. Please suggest.

```
# Request authorization via MainDB using Company ID
response = Excon.post(
  "https://MainDB_APIEndpoint/#{Customer_Id}/login",
  headers: { 'Authorization' => API_TOKEN }
)

# Get the login URL from the response
login_url = JSON.parse(response.body)['login_url']

# Make a request to the MainDB API for that tenant to auth with that tenant
response = Excon.get(login_url)

# Extract the cookies which will be used to auth future MainDB API requests for this tenant
cookies = response.data[:cookies].join('; ')

#Uses the cookie to make API calls to that customer 
response = Excon.get(
"https://MainDB_APIEndpoint/sales/tickets",
 headers: { 'Cookie' => cookies })

#Parses and returns result from the first page
page_data = JSON.parse(response.body)

csv = CSV.open('./output1_ticket.csv', 'w')
headers = nil
page_data['results'].each do |result|
    if headers.nil?
        headers = result.keys
        csv << headers
    end
    csv << headers.map { |key| result[key] }
end

#Tried getting all the JSON pages but this doesn't seem to work
pages = Excon.get(
"https:/MainDB_APIEndpoint/sales/tickets/?page=5",
query: { page: page })
```

Comment: Have you tried using this syntax? `connection = Excon.new('https:/MainDB_APIEndpoint/sales/tickets'); connection.get(query: { page: page })`

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. That worked. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509291/andrei

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax:

```
connection = Excon.new('https:/MainDB_APIEndpoint/sales/tickets')
connection.get(query: { page: page })
```